# What type should I give to script tags when Webpack bundles are emitted as modules?

Tags: javascript, webpack, es6-modules, bundling-and-minification

In our project we recently moved to start emitting modules for our javascript bundles using the [`module` config](https://webpack.js.org/configuration/output/#outputmodule) in webpack.

From my understanding we should be including our bundles with the type `module` as described here: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/script#attr-type

Here is an example of one of our project's script tags:

`<script data-chunk="main" src="http://localhost:1124/static/js/modern.framework-node_modules_react-.js" crossorigin="anonymous" defer type="module"></script>`

One gap in my knowledge I'd like to understand is whether *every* bundle should have the type `module`? In our project our client entrypoint is configured [here](https://github.com/bbc/simorgh/blob/1d272418eaf16305fc793a47f232a2a4ac322a30/webpack.config.client.js#L53) in webpack. This client code must be triggered to execute when script is downloaded, it will begin the process of hydrating our clientside app and then onwards to import the various modules we've emitted from the webpack bundling process. If this clientside code is packaged up as a module, what actually triggers the entrypoint to execute? And leading on from this question does that mean that the bundle containing entrypoint should omit the type attribute as it needs to execute immediately?

The aim of this question is configure our javascript bundles to load as efficiently as possible, I'm unsure if our current setup is achieving this.

Comment: A script body is always executed when loading, module or not. If you want to use `import` and `export`, it has to be a module. If you want declarations to implicitly attach to `window` as global symbols, then a script has to **not** be a module. Otherwise, it doesn't really make much difference, and certainly not a difference in "efficiency".

Comment: Thanks @Pointy, so I imagine webpack must include a 'immediately executed script' that imports modules and begins hydrating our clientside appliation. And that script although declared as a module will execute straightaway, am I following you correctly?

Comment: Yes, the code in a module must be executed by the browser when it is loaded in order for the module to make sense.

Comment: Thanks again @Pointy, sounds like I can safely mark all my scripts as `type="module"`.